# Laravel sorting merged collections

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 collections being merged in my `controller`, my problem is I want the merged collection to be sorted by `expiry_date`.

```
    $expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months'));
    $servers = Server::where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->orderBy('expiry_date', 'asc')->get();
    $domains = Domain::where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->orderBy('expiry_date', 'asc')->get();
    $hosts = Host::where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->orderBy('expiry_date', 'asc')->get();
    $invoices = $domains->merge($servers)->merge($hosts);
```

Comment: Just a note: I’d make a trait that contains a `scopeExpiresAfter($query, DateTimeInterface $date)` method, that you can apply to your `Server`, `Domain`, and `Host` models. This will then clean you code up a bit: `Server::expiresAfter($threeMonths)->get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using SQL queries, in case anyone is looking for something similar.

```
$servers = DB::table('servers')->select(DB::raw('"Server" as type, servers.id, servers.client_id, servers.expiry_date, servers.name, clients.name as clientName'))->leftJoin('clients', 'servers.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')->where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry);
    $domains = DB::table('domains')->select(DB::raw('"Domain" as type, domains.id, domains.client_id, domains.expiry_date, domains.name, clients.name as clientName'))->leftJoin('clients', 'domains.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')->where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry);
    $hosts = DB::table('hosts')->select(DB::raw('"Host" as type, hosts.id, hosts.client_id, hosts.expiry_date, hosts.name, clients.name as clientName'))->leftJoin('clients', 'hosts.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')->where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->unionAll($domains)->unionAll($servers)->orderBy('expiry_date', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `orderBy()` works properly inside your queries, this should work for you:

```
$expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months'));
$servers = Server::where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->get();
$domains = Domain::where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->get();
$hosts = Host::where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->get();
$invoices = $domains->merge($servers)->merge($hosts);
$invoices->sortBy('expiry_date');
```

Comment: Do you get any error? If not, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: `asort() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given` I tried without the asc and no error but it was not sorted

Comment: Try to use `->sortBy('expiry_date')` then.